# Rails Pass Parameters Via URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement searching in my rails app. I have a `User` model where each user has an `id` and a `facebook_id`.

How can I implement searching by `facebook_id`? I was looking to call something like this: `localhost:3000/users.json?facebook_id=123456`.

Thanks!

**Edit**: I tried a conditional index, but received an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

This was my code:

```
  def index
    if params[:facebook_id]
      respond_with User.find(params:facebook_id)
    elsif params[:twitter_id]
      respond_with User.find(params:twitter_id)
    else
      respond_with User.all
    end
  end
```

Rails log:

```
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users.json?facebook_id=1" for 173.247.200.7 at 2012-08-07 19:43:11 +0000
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as JSON
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"facebook_id"=>"1"}
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (undefined local variable or method `facebook_id' for #<UsersController:0x000000044b6e38>):
2012-08-07T19:43:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

**Edit2**: After changing the params from `params:facebook_id` to `params[:facebook_id]` I received another error. Here is a copy of my rails log.

```
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users.json?facebook_id=1000" for 173.247.200.7 at 2012-08-07 19:53:45 +0000
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as JSON
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"facebook_id"=>"1000"}
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=1000):
2012-08-07T19:53:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing the params hash wrongly (you are doing `params:facebook_id` and it should be `params[:facebook_id]`). Try this:

```
def index
    if params[:facebook_id]
      respond_with User.find(params[:facebook_id])
    elsif params[:twitter_id]
      respond_with User.find(params[:twitter_id])
    else
      respond_with User.all
    end
  end
```

The second error (of your second edit) comes because you are trying to fetch a User that doesn't exist (id = 1000). This happens because you are looking for the User by its primary key (id). From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

> Model.find(primary_key) will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
>   exception if no matching record is found.

If you want to fetch by the **facebook id**, you should be able to do this:

```
User.find_by_facebook_id(params[:facebook_id])
```

This kind of finders are called [Dynamic Finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders) which basically lets you do stuff like:

```
Model.find_by_field
```

Where field is any field or attribute of the table that is related to your Model.

Comment: Woah, don't know how I missed the []! Give me one sec and I'll try it out.

Comment: Read the error. It's obvious what is happening, no? You are trying to fetch a User with Id = 1000, which doesn't exist.

Comment: It is searching for a User with id=1000, instead of with facebook_id=1000. Why?

Comment: Because you are doing User.find. Try doing User.find_by_facebook_id(params[:facebook_id])

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. You can add a query parameter as you suggested and in your controller add logic that will search the user if facebook_id is present.
`:facebook_id` will be available in your controller action that matches the URL. In your case it is probably the `User#index` action.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a search form in the View:

```
<%= form_tag user_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Something like the following in the Controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

And then in the Model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['facebook_id LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
  find(:all)
  end
end
```